# alert handshake failure Certbot

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, certbot

I have a server that runs in NodeJS (express) and I have an issue when trying to to make it https. I was able to manually create a certificate using Certbot

```
certbot certonly --manual
```

after that, I set up my express app

```
const fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');

const credentials = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example/privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example/cert.pem', 'utf8'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example/chain.pem', 'utf8')
};

const app = express();

// Starting both http & https servers
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
  console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

but now when I try to access my page via https protocol I am getting errors

in Chrome:

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

in Firefox:

```
SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

and when I run curl -I

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

or curl -Iv

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://example.com/
*   Trying 90.80.200.30...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (90.80.200.30) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I have a server that runs in NodeJS (express) and I have an issue when trying to to make it https. I was able to manually create a certificate using Certbot

```
certbot certonly --manual
```

after that, I set up my express app

```
const fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');

const credentials = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example/privkey.pem', 'utf8'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example/cert.pem', 'utf8'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example/chain.pem', 'utf8')
};

const app = express();

// Starting both http & https servers
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
  console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

but now when I try to access my page via https protocol I am getting errors

in Chrome:

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

in Firefox:

```
SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
```

*curl -I*

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

*curl -Iv*

```
* Rebuilt URL to: https://example.com/
*   Trying 90.80.200.30...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to example.com (90.80.200.30) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

*openssl x509 -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem --noout --text*

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 31 12:53:53 2018 GMT
            Not After : Jan 29 12:53:53 2019 GMT
        Subject: CN = example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                      30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:
                                  …
                      3E:E7:FE:74:88:FB:A4:8F:28:93:01:9D:DD:F1:DB:FE
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:65:D0:3F:65:D0:3F:D0:3F:65:D0
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:65:D0:3F:65:D0:3F

            Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
                CA Issuers - URI:http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:example.com
            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1
                  CPS: http://cps.letsencrypt.org
                  User Notice:
                    Explicit Text: This Certificate may only be relied upon by Relying Parties and only in accordance with the Certificate Policy found at https://letsencrypt.org/repository/

            CT Precertificate SCTs:
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:
                                30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F
                    Timestamp : Oct 31 13:53:53.601 2018 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:
                                            …
                                3E:E7:FE:74:88:FB:A4:8F:28:93:01:9D:DD:F1:DB:FE
                Signed Certificate Timestamp:
                    Version   : v1 (0x0)
                    Log ID    : 30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:
                                30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:
                    Timestamp : Oct 31 13:53:53.593 2018 GMT
                    Extensions: none
                    Signature : ecdsa-with-SHA256
                                30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:
                                            …
                                3E:E7:FE:74:88:FB:A4:8F:28:93:01:9D:DD:F1:DB:FE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
                  30:44:02:20:4A:48:E9:34:36:94:72:A9:DD:65:D0:3F:
                              …
                  3E:E7:FE:74:88:FB:A4:8F:28:93:01:9D:DD:F1:DB:FE
```

*openssl s_client -connect example.com:443*

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = example.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=example.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Ui1+nIYuYX9pfi+lQMchiMS90xsM7g0LtHP2ya1/2IgizLY4IjM/MXO6ykVa6JU8
                    …
eXB0Lm9yZy9yZXBvc2l0b3J5LzCCAQMGCisGAQQB1nkCBAIEgfQEgfEA7wB1AOJp
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=example.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3429 bytes and written 302 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 99A2269E79E79E762624A77229E762629E79E7BE1C19E7CB30499E7092269E72620A6C9E7
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 9E79451F4C469E79E7925ED689E79EAB79E7989E799E799E79213779E799E799E799E799E799E79EFCC152D
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 300 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg
    0000 - c4 6d 99 ee 27 d7 e6 c7-ad 67 d2 e9 f4 5c 74 67   .m..'....g...\tg


    Start Time: 1541064686
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

*nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers example.com*

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-11-01 10:36 CET
Nmap scan report for example.com (90.80.200.30)
Host is up (0.0047s latency).
Not shown: 990 closed ports
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   open     ftp
22/tcp   open     ssh
53/tcp   open     domain
80/tcp   open     http
443/tcp  open     https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - F
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: indeterminate
|     cipher preference error: Too few ciphers supported
|   TLSv1.1:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - F
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: indeterminate
|     cipher preference error: Too few ciphers supported
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - F
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: indeterminate
|     cipher preference error: Too few ciphers supported
|_  least strength: F
1433/tcp filtered ms-sql-s
1723/tcp open     pptp
2000/tcp open     cisco-sccp
8082/tcp filtered blackice-alerts
8291/tcp open     unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 15.81 seconds
```

---

I was trying to figure out what could be causing this issue and or how could I solve it but I was not able to figure anything out, I tried updating OpenSSL to the latest version, I tried to regenerate the certificate but nothing helped, I'd be very happy for any help whatsoever.

Comment: The problem is not related to the certificate but the TLS configuration in your webserver or its interaction with your client. You should try also another client like `openssl s_client` towards your server.

Comment: I tried openssl s_client and also nmap (I added them above)